# Zurb Foundation components not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

Zurb Foundation 6 [Custom package](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download.html/) with **All components.**
For example. How to enable Off-Canvas? 
The CSS file (foundation.css) has necessary styles and in JS file (foundation.js) has some references. No more files are missing. 
In any packages...
[image: folder structure]

Comment: You should show a minimal example with html code that shows how you try to use foundation. Beside that, did you call `$(document).foundation()`  at the end of the document or in your jQuery ready callback?

Comment: @t.niese
It does not work even an [example](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html#setup)  from the official site. `$(document).foundation()` is the end of the markup

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the package, make sure you include the componet in your html and calling it. make sure you follow the instructions as noted here:

http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html#setup

also create a button to toggle the off canvas:

```
<button type="button" class="button" data-toggle="offCanvas">Open Menu</button>
```

and init the new off-canvas element at your JS file:

```
var elem = new Foundation.OffCanvas(element, options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Helped. But I'm still not satisfied. In the version 5.3. * Is usually small text-center, in the version 6 such a rule is not! This is not the only thing missing rule! I'm not understand, why?!

Comment: i dont get exactly the problem. can you try to explain more?